# How does this manipulation of summations work?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

I am reading some mathematics in which is the following algebraic manipulation.

$$
\begin{align}
\exp(x)\exp(y) & = \left(\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}\right) \left(\sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{y^m}{m!}\right) \\
& = \sum_{n, m = 0}^\infty \frac{x^n y^m}{n! m!} \\
& = \sum_{n, m = 0}^\infty \frac{(n + m)!}{n! m!} x^n y^m \frac{1}{(n + m)!} \\
& = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \sum_{n = 0}^k \left[\frac{k!}{n!(k - n)!}x^n y^{k - n} \right] \frac{1}{k!} \\
\end{align}
$$

I haven't yet understood the step from the third line to the fourth line.
In particular, where does the $\sum_{n = 0}^k$ in the fourth line appear from?
I would appreciate help to understand this.

NB: I assume that $\sum_{n, m = 0}^\infty \frac{x^n y^m}{n! m!}$ is shorthand for $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{x^n y^m}{n! m!}.$
I think that this assumption is correct, but please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: I'll add as a comment since there already is an answer.  Check out: https://www.google.com/search?q=summation+triangular+array&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=LsRoVemgG8ilsAXBqIH4Aw&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1266&bih=607#imgrc=TBdoYGcfrOzuhM%253A%3B8LyGC4y6-R4CEM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fpatentimages.storage.googleapis.com%252FWO2006031747A2%252Fimgf000006_0001.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252Fpatents%252FWO2006031747A2%253Fcl%253Den%3B1567%3B731   Normally you are adding up all elements of one columns with those of the next, etc.  This change of variables is like adding up along the diagonals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\sum_{n,m=0}^\infty A(n,m,n+m) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^k A(n,n-k,k)
$$
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccccccc}
& m=0 & m=1 & m=2 & m=3 & \cdots \\
\hline
n=0 & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \circ & \cdots \\
n=1 & \bullet & \bullet & \circ & \cdots \\
n=2 & \bullet & \circ & \cdots \\
n=3 & \circ & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots
\end{array}
$$
Look at the diagonal where "$\circ$" appears instead of "$\bullet$".  Those are the entries in which $k=3$.  As you move downward and to the left along that diagonal, you have $n=0$, then $n=1$, then $n=2$, then $n=3$; hence $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^3=\sum_{n=0}^k$.

Notice that in every entry on that diagonal you have $n+m=3$, i.e. $n+m=k$.  So in the expression $A(n,m,n+m)$, where $n+m$ appears, it is replaced by $k$, in $A(n,n-k,k)$.  Since $n+m=k$, we have $m=k-n$, so where $m$ appears in places where it is not in the expression $n+m$, we put $k-n$ in its place.

Answer (score 2):

Since the sum is absolutely convergent, we can sum in any order.

In the fourth line, we just sum along the diagonals $n+m = \text{constant}$.

This is known as a Cauchy product: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product